# How to call a function with arguments using ThreadPool in C#

Tags: c#, function, threadpool

Following suggestions in another post I've been able to write the code below for an app that uses multithreading and 
has a start button and a stop button. The start button calls a function that takes several minutes to complete. The Stop button stops the execution of the Function whenever I want.

The code works perfect with the SlowFunction() that doesn't have arguments, but my real function needs an string 
argument to work and is defined like this:

```
public void SlowFunction(string str) {...}
```

Then, my issue is that I cannot call the Function with arguments inside the "**WaitCallback(...)**" part.

In this code since the **SlowFunction()** doesnt have arguments, there is no issue and I can call the function like this

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SlowFunction), cts.Token);
```

But if instead of use **SlowFunction()** that doesn't need arguments, I use this new **SlowFunction1(Somestring)** that needs a mandatory string argument:

```
    public void SlowFunction1(string sec)
    {
        double sec1 = Convert.ToDouble(sec);
        var end = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec1);
        while (DateTime.Now < end)
        { }
        MessageBox.Show("Process finished1");
    }
```

***I cannot call it using:***

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SlowFunction1(Somestring)), cts.Token);
```

***How can I use WaitCallback() to call SlowFunction1 with argument?
How would be modified the definition of SlowFunction1?*** I've tried something like below but is not working.

```
    public void SlowFunction(string str, object obj)
    {
        CancellationToken token = (CancellationToken)obj;
        ..
    }
```

My current working code with the SlowFunction that doesn't need argument is below. Thanks for any help.

```
namespace SampleStartStop
{    
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {       
        // Create the token source.
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cts != null)
            {
                cts.Cancel();
            }           
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SlowFunction), cts.Token);                         
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cts != null)
            {
                cts.Cancel();
                cts = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Processing cancelled");
            }   
        }
        public void SlowFunction(object obj)
        {
            CancellationToken token = (CancellationToken)obj;

            var end = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4);
            while (DateTime.Now < end)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {                
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Processing finished");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of doing this, below are a few:

1 Use the `state` argument to pass a single variable

```
void Method1( object state )
{
    var sec = (string)state;
    // use sec here
}

// call this using
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( Method1, "20" );
```

2 Use the `state` argument to pass an object containing multiple variables

```
class Foo
{
    public string Seconds { get; set; }
    public int OtherStuff { get; set; }
}

void Method2( object state )
{
    var args = (Foo)state;          
    // use args.Seconds and args.OtherStuff here
}

// call this like so:
var args = new Foo()
{
    Seconds = "20",
    OtherStuff = 4711
};

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( Method2, args );
```

3 Create a worker class that contains both the variables and the code

```
class Worker
{
    public string Seconds { get; set; }
    public int OtherStuff { get; set; }

    public void DoWork( object unused )
    {
        // use this.Seconds and this.OtherStuff here
    }
}

// call like so:
var worker = new Worker()
{
    Seconds = "20",
    OtherStuff = 4711
};

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( worker.DoWork );
```

4 Use an anonymous delegate

```
string sec = "20";

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( delegate
                              {
                                  // use sec here            
                              } );
```

Comment: Do we really need those bold headers? It simply adds noise.

Comment: Nah I guess they did turn out a little too bold hehe.

Comment: Hello Chris, Thanks for share those 4 ways to do it, I still don'e see too much clear how to use them. Should I insert the call to the function within the commented lines you put? and instead of using the string, use this.seconds? May you show me an example more detailed in how would be with delegate please

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that you're using .Net4.0 or above. There is no reason to use `ThreadPool.Queue...` directly. Use [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it provides many useful features.

Simple way to the problem is to use lambda expressions.

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cts != null)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }           
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> SlowFunction(SomeString, cts.Token), cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);                       
}

public void SlowFunction(string str, CancellationToken token)
{
    //Your code
}
```

Note that you don't need to type the `CancellationToken` as `object` anymore. It can be strongly typed.

Also be aware that [StartNew is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). If you're in .Net4.5 use `Task.Run`, otherwise specify the `TaskScheduler` explicitly.

Comment: Hi Sriram, thanks for your help. I was able to implement your solution and it works with StarNew and with Task.Run. Thank you!!